# Is there a way to have a custom addon preference persist across auto updates and reinstalling the addon?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm trying to keep certain values for an addon to persist across versions of the addon either by auto update or the user reinstalling the addon manually. For example, the code below saves the custom value in the `config/userpref.blend` file but that is erased upon reinstalling the addon. Is there a best practice for this? I could save a file in the blender program directory I suppose but that seems not great.

```
class MyPreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __package__
    custom_id: StringProperty(default='')
```